# How do you pass values from a textbox to a public property in a class?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, textbox, public

I need to pass code that user enters into a Textbox to a Public Property within a class. Here is my code.

**Form2.vb Code**

```
Public Class Form2
Dim class2A As part2Class = New part2Class()
Dim class2B As part2BClass = New part2BClass()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim a As Integer = CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)
    Dim b As Integer = CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)

    part2Class._Num1 = a
    part2Class._Num2 = b


End Sub
```

Here is my code in **part2Class.vb**

```
Public Class part2Class

    Public Property _Num1
    Public Property _Num2
    Public Overridable Function Calculate() As Integer
        Return _Num1 + _Num2
    End Function

End Class
```

I get an error saying "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." How do I pass the values from the textboxes to the public property values?

Thanks!

Comment: `part2Class` is a class not an object.  It is like a blueprint for what objects created from it should do and the data they will store.  `Dim myObject As New part2Class` creates an object.  It would behoove you to work on the names you give things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a class first before accessing it's members:

```
Dim objpart2Class as part2Class = new part2Class()
objpart2Class._Num1 = a
objpart2Class._Num2 = b
```